# "store.RevisionNotAvailable" error while installing a package with Snapcraft

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, microk8s, snapcraft

I was trying to install microk8s on my Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS by executing this command:

```
sudo snap install microk8s -- classic
```

However I got this error:

```
error: store.RevisionNotAvailable with 2 snaps
```

Does anyone know what is causing this error and how to fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the space between the dash and "classic"...

The correct command is:

```
sudo snap install microk8s --classic
```